# Is there a way to "bundle" the graphics with the Web App?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm developing a JavaScript application using the Google UI Service that I want to eventually deploy as a Google Web App.

I'd like to include several graphics in the user interface, but I'm finding the documentation for this on the Google developer pages quite thin.

Is there a way to "bundle" the graphics used in the app with the Web App?

Or do they need to be publicly available on a web page and referenced in the Web App by URL?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bundle them. You have to have them available publicly on the Internet and you can only create an Image object with the URL.